# Browser used cache without revalidate

Tags: javascript, ajax, caching, browser

I am trying to learning the browser's (Chrome/Firefox) cache mechanism.
I set up a simple HTML:

```
    <HTML><BODY>
    Hellow World

    <script>
        function loadJS(){ 
           var s = document.createElement('script'); 
           s.setAttribute('src','/myscript');
           document.body.appendChild(s);
        } 
        loadJS()
    </script>

    <BODY></HTML>
```

I output "`Cache-Control: max-age:30`" for "/myscript"

Everytime I press F5, browser will re-validate /myscript with my server to get a 304 back.

But if I use

```
setTimeout(loadJS, 1);
```

Everytime I press F5, it looks like browser will check expire time, and if not expired, browser will use the cache directly instead of going to server for revalidation.

My question is:

1. Why? is there a detail explanation for this?
2. Does it mean if I want browser to use cache and reduce network request as much as possible, I need to wait the page loaded, and then request resources by js later?

Comment: How do you know that it is not requesting it from the server? are you checking the network from an external program? (fiddler maybe?)

Comment: I used Chrome' web developer tool to monitor the network request.

Answer (score 0):

I've done a fair amount of experimentation with browser cache control, and I am surprised that no one has posted an answer.

Many people do not pay attention to this.  As a results websites--for no reason at all--make browsers perform useless roundtrips for a `304-not modified` on images, js or css files which are unlikely changed in 5 years--like who is going to change jquery.v-whatever?

So anyway, I have found that when you hard refresh the browser using F5 or ctrl-r, Chrome will revalidate just about everything on the page--as it should.  This is very helpful and is why you want keep the etags in the response header.

When testing your max-age and expires headers, browse the site as a user naturally would by clicking the links on the page.   Watch the web server's logfile (I use http://www.apacheviewer.com) and you'll get a good idea of how the browsers are caching.

Setting the headers works.  I posted this a while back: [Apache: set max-age or expires in .htaccess for directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16750757/apache-set-max-age-or-expires-in-htaccess-for-directory)

The easiest way for me to manage the web server is to create a /cache directory and instruct apache to set a 1 year max-age and expires header for everything in every subdir.

It works wonders.  My pages make 1 round trip to the server, where as they used to make 3-5 trips with each request, just to get a 304.

Write your html as you normally would.  The browsers will obey the cache settings in the headers.

Just know that hard refreshing the browser causes the browser to ignore max-age and relies on etags.